# Is it "wrong" to issue a SQLite INSERT that doesn't call sqlite3_bind?

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm writing a custom SQLite wrapper for a MacOS game that is just for fun.  I've studied a very nice tutorial [SQLite With Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6620276-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started) and it outlines a laborious method for constructing an INSERT statement that uses bind calls like this:

```
let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO Contact (Id, Name) VALUES (?, ?);"
insert(id:4, name:"Chris")

func insert(id: Int32, name: NSString) {

    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

        sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 1, id)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, name.utf8String, -1, nil)

        if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not insert row.")
        }

    } else {
        print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
}
```

Instead I found that the following works just as well and precludes having to bind the data to the statement.  Is it risky to write it this way? I realize prepared statements are faster/more efficient but I don't need speed for my purposes. I don't see examples like the following anywhere.   Thanks for any advice - I've just started learning Swift and keep finding things a bit harder than I thought they would be.

```
let insertItemSql : String = "INSERT INTO item (itemid, characterClass, 
itemtype, itemtypeid,  mincharges, maxcharges, name) VALUES (%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,'%@');"

let sqlHelper = SQLHelper(databasePath: Globals.SharedInstance.databaseUrl)
let command = String(format: insertItemSql, item.id, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, item.name)
let success = sqlHelper.nonQuery(sqlCommand: command)


func nonQuery(sqlCommand cmd: String) -> Bool {

        var success : Bool = false

        if let db = openDatabase() {

            var nonQueryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
            if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, cmd, -1, &nonQueryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
                if sqlite3_step(nonQueryStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                    success = true
                } else {
                    print("Could not execute nonQuery statement.")
                    if let errorPointer = sqlite3_errmsg(db) {
                        let message = String.init(cString: errorPointer)
                        print("Error message was " + message)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("nonQuery statement could not be prepared")
                if let errorPointer = sqlite3_errmsg(db) {
                    let message = String.init(cString: errorPointer)
                    print("Error message was " + message)
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(nonQueryStatement)

        }

        return success

    }
```

Comment: I disagree.  Security is important, but not in a localized context involving a game and where the app domain is running on a single machine, which I did specifically call out, hoping to prevent comments like yours.  I appreciate you reading my question, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You’re missing the point. The issue is not the SQL injection attack, but the fact that user input that includes a `'` character will break your code. SQL injection is a malicious example of the broader problem. But I’ll delete that link given that you’ve taken offense. None was intended.

Answer (score 2):

It would be an overstatement to say that it’s “wrong”, but it can be fragile and generally isn’t considered best practice. That tutorial’s advice to [bind values](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) is a good technique.

For example, what if the value associated with the `name` column had a `'` in it? E.g. “O'Connor”. The single quote in this string will prematurely terminate your SQL string, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO item (itemid, characterClass, itemtype, itemtypeid,  mincharges, maxcharges, name)
    VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,'O'Connor');
```

In this scenario (amongst others), the prepare of a manually constructed SQL statement can fail. The `sqlite3_bind_text` eliminates this class of problem and is always safe. As [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_sql_length) says:

> Then use the [`sqlite3_bind_XXXX()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions to bind your large string values to the SQL statement. The use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the string, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks. It is also runs faster since the large string does not need to be parsed or copied as much.

Sure, if you *know* that you’ll never have any problematic input (e.g. it’s just numerics or internal string values that you know can never have any of these problematic values), then you don’t have to use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions, but that the sort of assumption that tends to bite us later on.

As a general rule, binding values is safer. And if you’re concerned about the `sqlite3_bind_text` sort of syntax as being cumbersome, then I might suggest a SQLite wrapper class that does the binding for you, but abstracts you away from those details.

---

By the way the other advantage of binding is for `NULLABLE` columns. If you just use `?` placeholders, then you can bind either `NULL` or a proper value for that column. If you’re building SQL manually, proper handling of `NULLABLE` columns is just a little more complicated.

Comment: It's easy to sanitize inputs.   What I'm surprised is that I've not seen an example in SQLite literature about the possibility of execution sans binding.   If I were to use a SQL engine in a real world scenario, I'd use an engine that supported stored procedures that has a more robust interface than this low level C style API.

Comment: Good point on the nullability.   I had not considered that.   Oh, and I'm not offended at all.  Takes a lot to offend me on the interwebs.. :-)